# Why the data of this particular URL is not written in my command line?

Tags: node.js, express, https

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    const url = ("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid={my ID}");

    https.get(url, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })

    res.send("server is up and running")
})


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is runniong on port 3000.");
})
```

Recently, I saw a lecture from Au Angela's full-stack web development course, and I did what she had done, however my command line was empty when I refreshed the localhost:3000.

[her command line result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmohm.png)
[her code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zm7O.png)

Comment: Did you log on to the app's route where the sites hosted? cause the code is perfectly fine and should work if you visit localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Don't use parentheses when you declare a string in JavaScript.
Try this:

```
const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid={my ID}";
```

Comment: The parentheses are removed but still nothing appears in my command line